# How Can I Make WordPress's <?php the_title_attribute(); ?> Render %20 for Spaces?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, standards

I'm trying to render a WordPress theme that is 100% HTML5 compliant, and have managed my way through all but one snag.

At the end of certain posts I show a "Tweet" link, which uses the following source code in the Theme template:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>&amp;via=ianhines&amp;url=<?php echo simple_url_shortener('','service=bit.ly+key&apikey=R_a6dc414291bb882024ddd99690f5eb61&login=ianhines&cache=no'); ?>" title="Share This Article on Twitter">Tweet</a>
```

HTML5 forbids having spaces in URLs. They must be rendered as `%20`. However, `<?php the_title_attribute; ?>` renders an XHTML safe version of the Post Title with spaces maintained.

An example URL (rendered using the template source code above):

```
a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=Twitter, Reblog, and Email Comments&via=ianhines&url=http://ihin.es/eCoYN9" title="Share This Article on Twitter">Tweet</a>
```

Is there any way I can force WordPress to render the spaces in this URL string as %20, and thereby make my site fully HTML5 compliant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just wrap the `the_title_attribute()` with [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/urlencode):

```
/share?text=<?php echo urlencode(the_title_attribute()); ?>&amp;via=
```

**Edit:** Ok, due to that comment, you'd need to do something like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
the_title_attribute();
$title = ob_get_clean();
?>
/share?text=<?php echo urlencode($title); ?>&amp;via=
```

**Edit2:** Looking at [the docs for `the_title_attribute`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute):

```
/share?text=<?php echo urlencode(the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>&amp;via=
```

Comment: `the_title_attribute()` actually `echo` es the text, so this won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $spaceurl=the_title_attribute('echo=0');
    $nonspaceurl=preg_replace('\s','%20',spaceurl);
?>

<a href="<?php echo $nonspaceurl; ?>">
    my link text
</a>
```

**EDIT**

I added `echo=0` to return the text instead of displaying it, see [`the_title_attribute`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute).

Answer (score 2):

A value of 0 passed to `the_title_attribute()` makes it return rather than echo it's result.

```
<?php 
  $urltitle= str_replace(' ','%20',the_title_attribute('echo=0')); //value of 0 to return rather than echo result  
?> 

<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php echo $urltitle; ?>&amp;via=ianhines&amp;url=<?php echo simple_url_shortener('','service=bit.ly+key&apikey=R_a6dc414291bb882024ddd99690f5eb61&login=ianhines&cache=no'); ?>" title="Share This Article on Twitter">Tweet</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the echo param of `the_title_attribute()` and `urlencode()` the spaces:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=<?php echo urlencode(the_title_attribute('', '', 0)); ?>&amp;via=ianhines&amp;url=<?php echo simple_url_shortener('','service=bit.ly+key&apikey=R_a6dc414291bb882024ddd99690f5eb61&login=ianhines&cache=no'); ?>" title="Share This Article on Twitter">Tweet</a>
```